# how to access openAI universe

Tags: python, openai-gym

I have gone through all of the steps at the openAI installation page(https://mc.ai/getting-started-with-openai-gym/) However, I cannot find a way to get into the universe. I looked through my directory and found a universe folder, but I don't understand what the organizational structure of the data needs to look like. In other words, where the universe folder should be. I have been at this for four hours without luck. How do I access the Universe?

```
import gym
import universe

env = gym.make('flashgames.DuskDrive-v0')
env.configure(remotes=1)
```

code returns:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'universe'

Answer (score 1):

did you follow all the instructions?

`git clone https://github.com/openai/universe.git
cd universe
pip install -e .`

take a look again if so https://github.com/openai/universe and notice that universe is deprecated by https://github.com/openai/retro.

Comment: This i s the error I got from that:   (DETAIL: original error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'go': 'go'.)

Comment: maybe you are missing execute this 

on OSX : 

`pip install numpy incremental`
`brew install golang libjpeg-turbo`


On Ubuntu: 

`pip install numpy`
`sudo apt-get install golang libjpeg-turbo8-dev make`

Comment: ==> jpeg-turbo
jpeg-turbo is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because libjpeg-turbo is not linked to prevent conflicts with the standard libjpeg.

If you need to have jpeg-turbo first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/jpeg-turbo/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find jpeg-turbo you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/jpeg-turbo/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/jpeg-turbo/include" - this is what I got back